# Opened port for WAN not working (whats wrong)?

Tags: ubuntu, port, odoo

I need to open port 8069 on external IP. from router point, internal-ip and port 8069 was set (to forward to that local ip). So it should be possible to connect from external-ip:8069 to internal-ip:8069? But for some reason it is not working.

Locally I can connect with internal-ip:8069 to openerp server (through browser or gtk client).
Do I miss something? Because outside lan, it is not possible to connect to that port (while it is possible to connect to other ports (but on different internal-ips).

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.170
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.115
```

/etc/deny.hosts:

```
#there is no hosts to be denied
```

/etc/allow.hosts:

```
sshd: ALL:ALLOW
```

What I am missing?

Comment: This may be considered [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific settings to make in your openerp server computer, you just need to configure your Internet router for forwarding internal `8069` port of your `192.168.1.170` machine to the external port of your choice of the router.

Please make a google search with "how to configure port forwarding YOURROUTERBRAND" to find some easy tutorials.

Else go to your router config page (`http://192.168.1.115`) and try it on your own.